# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $S,T:V \rightarrow V$ be linear. Is $ dim(S(ImT)) = rank (ST)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Restating the question in the title:

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $S$ and $T$ are linear maps within $V$. Then is  $ dim(S(ImT)) = rank (ST)$? If not, then what is $dim(S(ImT))$?

Also, is $dim(S(ImT)) \leq rankS$?

Comment: $dim(S(ImT))$ =rank($ST$) pretty much by definition of the rank of a linear map

Also, since $ImT \subset V$, $dimS(ImT) \leq dimS(V)=rankS$ is pretty much automatic

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I have edited my original post!

Comment: @ Sorin Tirc Thank you!